# MediaElement.js display audio player as black rectangle

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement.js, mediaelement

Since upgrading to MediaElement.js version 2.10.3 with WordPress 3.5.1, the audio player on my site appears as a black rectangle with a 'download' link, rather than the player. This occurs regardless of the theme used. This occurs in both Firefox and Safari on a Mac.

http://www.centenarypresbyterian.org.au/bible-talks/

(Other users have reported the same problem on the wordpress support forum - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-mediaelementjs-html5-video-audio-player-black-rectangle-no-audio-no-video-in-older-ie-browsers)

Comment: I see you managed to correct your problem. Can you please share how you did it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I noticed that on the settings page for the MediaElement plugin, I had no value in the "Default Type" field under "Audio Settings".  I set the value to "audio/mp3", and it started working again.  Don't know if that was a new field, or if the upgrade clobbered the value I had.

Comment: seems to be working for me now as well.

Also did the audio/mp3 trick, and changed the theme to 'ted'.